# Clickhouse CLI: Multi-statements are not allowed exception

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am trying to execute this query using the Clickhouse CLI:

`INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'Hello, world'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'def')`

which I found here: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/syntax

but it shows me the following error:

```
Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error (Multi-statements are not allowed): failed at position 17 (end of query) (line 1, col 17)
```

Could you please help me to fix that? I do not understand how to run queries like this using the CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this in the CLI to allow the multi-statements:

```
clickhouse-client --multiline --multiquery
```

Comment: This shouldnt be needed if you're executing queries in isolation and only if you're running multiples queries at once e.g. create before. The above insert is still a single query